# NSEvent - NSLeftMouseDown

Tags: cocoa, nsevent

I'm trying to trigger basic functions using NSEvent and mouse clicks. For example close the window when pressing left mouse button. What else do I need in this method?

Thanks.

```
 - (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

if ([theEvent type] == NSLeftMouseDown){

    [window orderOut:nil];

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is in a custom view and the `window` outlet is connected (or you fill in that variable with `[self window]` when the view is added to a superview), that should be all you need. I would suggest handling `mouseUp:` instead of `mouseDown:`, though, to give the user the opportunity to back out by moving the mouse outside of your view.

You might also consider using an NSButton instead of (or inside of) a custom view. You could hook it up directly to the window's `performClose:` or `orderOut:` action.